# Determine what type of biometric hardware is available Android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

I'm setting up a biometric login using kotlin. I have it working but I would like to switch out which icon is displayed based on the available hardware, ie. show a retinal scanner icon for retinal scanning, fingerprint for fingerprint scanning etc.
So far digging through the docs I haven't been able to find a way to determine this and the google machine hasn't been very useful.

something along the lines of

```
when (biometricManager.biometricType) {
face -> {}
fingerprint -> {}
retinaScanner -> {}
}
```

would be awesome. Does this exist?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, you use the package manager.

```
enum class BiometricType {
            Iris, Fingerprint, Face, None
        }

fun biometricType(context: Context): BiometricType {
        return when {
            context.applicationContext.packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_FACE) -> BiometricType.Face
            context.applicationContext.packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_FINGERPRINT) -> BiometricType.Fingerprint
            context.applicationContext.packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_IRIS) -> BiometricType.Iris
            else -> BiometricType.None
        }
    }
```

Hopefully this helps someone else out in the future